# Bind 10 - Reverse zone file error

Tags: windows-7, bind

As I stated in the title I have a problem with BIND 10 . More exactly , I am looking to make a reverse zone file. I am using BIND on Windows 7. I know, there were warnings about how ISC doesn't officially support BIND on Windows 7, but, here I am. The thing is, I am getting errors when I check the zone with **named-checkzone** .

```
C:\bind\bin>named-checkzone reversefastallpcrepair.com "c:/bind/etc/master/db/reversefastallpcrepair.com"

c:/bind/etc/master/db/reversefastallpcrepair.com:2: ignoring out-of-zone data (0.168.192.in-addr.arpa)          
zone reversefastallpcrepair.com/IN: has 0 SOA records           
zone reversefastallpcrepair.com/IN: has no NS records           
zone reversefastallpcrepair.com/IN: not loaded due to errors.
```

The reverse zone file looks like this:

```
$TTL 2000000           
0.168.192.in-addr.arpa. IN     SOA    ns1.fastallpcrepair.com. admin.fastallpcrepair.com. (         
                2014100105  ; Serial          
                3H          ; refresh after 3 hours          
                1H          ; retry after 1 hour         
                1W          ; expire after 1 week         
                1D)         ; minimum TTL of 1 day         

    ; Name Server
          IN     NS     ns1.fastallpcrepair.com.
          IN     NS     ns2.fastallpcrepair.com.         
60        IN     NS     ns1.fastallpcrepair.com.        
52        IN     NS     ns2.fastallpcrepair.com.
```

I searched and searched the errors of this sorts and tried to add $ORIGIN , remove it , put trailing dots wherever I need to, but nothing seems to work.
Can someone explain why it's returning these errors ? I am new to this, but I followed tutorials, and somewhere along the line I didn't do something as it should, I agree. I am still in learning phase. Your help would be much appreciated ! If you need any other resources, let me know .

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're running the `named-checkzone` command for the zone "reversefastallpcrepair.com" but the zone file is for the zone "0.168.192.in-addr.arpa."

Try `named-checkzone 0.168.192.in-addr.arpa c:/bind/etc...<filename>` instead.